# Bootstrap tabs on mobile / glyphicon and font resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have 4 tabs that contain a large glyphicon and some text, and they look great on desktops, however once it's shrunken down to mobile size, it looks a bit... naff!

**Mobile**

[image: Mobile]

**Desktop**
[image: Desktop]

**Mobile2**

[image: Mobile2]

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="row mt">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs centered" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#film" data-toggle="tab"><p><span class="fa fa-film large"></span></p><p>filming and editing</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#autocue" data-toggle="tab"><p><span class="fa fa-list-alt large"></span></p><p>autocue services</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#openers" data-toggle="tab"><p><span class="fa fa-play-circle-o large"></span></p><p>animation openers and stings</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#cbt" data-toggle="tab"><p><span class="fa fa-laptop large"></span></p><p>computer based training</p></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the only bit of applicable custom CSS

```
.large {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

The rest is just standard bootstrap.

Comment: How abt using `media queries`?

Comment: I was thinking about this, but it would need 2 different ones for both the glyphicon and the actual text? I thought there might be a better way?

Comment: Ok just tried a media query to simply change the glyphicon size but it seems to be a tab problem now... (see image **Mobile2**)

Comment: try applying this extra class to `<ul class="list-inline">`

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to combine media queries with Bootstrap's own variables:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
.font-size: 11px; // regular text
.large {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .font-size: 13px; // regular text
    .large {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .font-size: 16px; // regular text
    .large {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    .font-size: 18px; // regular text
    .large {
        font-size: 150px;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you set both the regular font size and the 'large' font size with the same queries.
Tweak the individual values as you see fit :)

Comment: Thank you, just tried this but seems to be a tab problem now (see new picture).

Comment: The problem there is that your whole set of tabs is fitted into a tight space, and it forces them to align horizontally next to eachother. The only way to free up more space for the text (if you don't want the make the text smaller) is by giving the individual tabs a response grid class. (col-md, col-lg, etc). This will make the tabs stack vertically once you go below a certain threshold. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I think I'll go with the grid option and adjust the font size slightly as I go. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for this media query:-

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.large {
    font-size: 10px; // Adjust this as required
   }
}
```